# Running cmd command to remote host on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, remote-access, invoke-command

I need to run in PowerShell script cmd command, which command will be running on remote cmd line. So I put in my script

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $line -scriptblock {cmd.exe /c "whoami"} -credential $Cred`

and it works, but only if on remote host was run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`
Otherwise I get error:

```
[192.168.1.1] Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.1 failed with the following error message : Access denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Trou
bleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (192.168.1.1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I need run that command to many (about 200) remote hosts, so the question is how can I do this without manually running on each remote host `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`? Server is in domain but romote hostd don't.

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are on a domain, you could enable PS Remoting on them all via Group Policy: https://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/

Comment: Server belongs to domain, but remote hosts don't.